# Unable to get the attribute value from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am unable to get the `status` attribute value. Can anyone please help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your picture of the code as code/text in a `code` section as described in the `help` section.

Answer (score 0):

The `Ack` element is also in namespace `http://www.moduslink...` therefore you need to prefix the location step in the xpath expression accordingly, else the select will be empty:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sub:Ack/@status"/>
```